# How to display lists side-by-side in R - a "cbind" for lists?

Tags: r, list, object

I am looking to use my screen real estate to look at several simple lists side by side.  I'm not trying to combine them, a la `cbind`, but I wouldn't mind if a new intermediate structure were created.  Realize, of course, that a list may have many different types of objects, though I will almost guarantee that my lists have the same structures; feel free to insert "NA" or "NULL" if necessary to make things work (or I can figure out how to wrangle that).

Here are three example lists that I would like to try to display side by side:

```
l1 <- list(e1 = "R", e2 = list("statistics", "visualization"), e3 = 0)
l2 <- list(e1 = "Perl", e2 = list("text processing", "scripting"), e3 = 0)
l3 <- list(e1 = "Matlab", e2 = list("numerical computing", "simulation"), e3 = c("academic - unknown", "professional - unknown"))
```

If you have a wide monitor, it looks like a waste to see these take up so much vertical room and so little room used on the horizontal access.  If these lists were just a little longer, I wouldn't be able to see more than 2 at a time, without reducing to a small font.

If it makes it easier, the `e3` entries in `l1` and `l2` could be `"FOSS"`, to match the character vectors of `l3$e3`, but the real goal is a layout problem in the R console.

Some naive, interface-specific solutions include:

- Fire up multiple R instances, split screen using GNU `screen` and `C-A |`
- Learn ESS, and let the miracle of Emacs solve everything
- Go back and forth with another text editor (e.g. Notepad++) and manually migrate blocks of text

The non-naive solutions that I'm trying are:

- Write these out to a text file.  The problem here is working out fixed width spacing.  Maybe `read.fwf` would help.  (It's okay to stop with an error if an entry would exceed the allotted space, or to truncate stuff.)
- Try something with the `reshape` package.
- Possibly something involving `xlsx`, to create a bunch of cells, each with text entries, and then attempt to display a big character matrix.

Are there some other methods that would be more efficient?  Again, nothing really needs to be combined as an object, just combined in the visual display.

---

Update 1.  Here is an example using `plyr`.  The results are admittedly quite crude - names of lists and list elements have not been preserved  That's not too hard to fix, but I suspect it's possible to do much better than this.  I'm okay with printing out the lists as R normally prints them, but separating the window in some way.  I have a suspicion that's not easy.

```
combineLists <- function(manyLists){
    library(plyr)
    newLists <- list()
    for(ixList in 1:length(manyLists)){
        tmpList <- lapply(manyLists[[ixList]], paste, sep = "", collapse = ", ")
        tmpVec  <- as.character(tmpList)
        newLists[[ixList]] <- tmpVec
    }
    newDF   <- t(ldply(newLists))
    return(newDF)
}

combineLists(list(l1, l2, l3))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine some  `capture.output`, `lapply`, `gsub` and `format` into a container.  Use `do.call` as a binding agent.  Add `paste` to taste. Let it brew for a while:

```
sidebyside <- function(..., width=60){
  l <- list(...)
  p <- lapply(l, function(x){
        xx <- capture.output(print(x, width=width))
        xx <- gsub("\"", "", xx)
        format(xx, justify="left", width=width)
      }
  )
  p <- do.call(cbind, p)
  sapply(seq_len(nrow(p)), function(x)paste(p[x, ], collapse=""))
}
```

This will cure everything:

```
sidebyside(l1, l2, l3, width=30)

 [1] "$e1                           $e1                           $e1                                              "
 [2] "[1] R                         [1] Perl                      [1] Matlab                                       "
 [3] "                                                                                                             "
 [4] "$e2                           $e2                           $e2                                              "
 [5] "$e2[[1]]                      $e2[[1]]                      $e2[[1]]                                         "
 [6] "[1] statistics                [1] text processing           [1] numerical computing                          "
 [7] "                                                                                                             "
 [8] "$e2[[2]]                      $e2[[2]]                      $e2[[2]]                                         "
 [9] "[1] visualization             [1] scripting                 [1] simulation                                   "
[10] "                                                                                                             "
[11] "                                                                                                             "
[12] "$e3                           $e3                           $e3                                              "
[13] "[1] 0                         [1] 0                         [1] academic - unknown     professional - unknown"
[14] "                                                                                                             "
```

Comment: Your answer is what I was hoping to achieve in base R.  James' answer is actually more attractive than I expected could be done, but your base R solution wins the "console" prize (versus consolation...).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `gplots::textplot`:

```
library(gplots)
textplot(cbind(l1,l2,l3))
```

It helps to maximise your window first.

Comment: +1 That's also quite good - it's also a clear, useful display.  The options for `mar` and `cex` seem to be handy.

Comment: It would help understand how useful this is if you showed a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a very clean solution,
but you could convert the lists to strings, 
put them in two separate files,
and call `diff -y` (or any similar application)
to display the differences between the two files.
Provided the structures are very similar,
they will be aligned.

```
cat(capture.output( print(l1) ), sep="\n", file="tmp1")
cat(capture.output( print(l2) ), sep="\n", file="tmp2")
system("diff -y tmp1 tmp2")
```

Comment: +1 I like that. Letting `diff` manage side-by-side presentation is clever.  `diff` functionality is quite useful.  If one wanted everything, it's not hard to prepend every line with a token unique for that source (i.e. the original list).  I only suspect that >2 lists will not work out so well.

Comment: Your idea can also be extended using the `paste` command.  However, the width of the different files makes the results jagged.  This leads me back to combining things via R with some kind of fixed width + string truncation / padding.  This would still make use of `capture.output()`, which is a good idea, and focuses on the *display* rather than the wrangling of list objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `unlist()`? And cheat them into rows?

```
for(x in 1:3) { 
print(rbind(unlist(get(paste("l",x,sep="")))))
}
```

You could set `use.names=FALSE` if you don't like the e1 e2 etc.

Comment: It's interesting, but my screen isn't *that* wide.  :)  Some of the text will spill over.  Fitting this columns, rather than rows, would be easier to process.

Comment: cbind() doesn't work very well with unlist if you have vectors > 1 in each element.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")
b <- c("1", "2", "3")

for (i in 1:length(a)){
   cat(paste0(a[i] , " ", b[i]), sep = "\n")}
```

Output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [lists](/questions/tagged/lists) [cat](/questions/tagged/cat)