# view or display lists side-by-side in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr

Is there a way to view lists side by side? I'm comparing two versions of the same dataset and would like to view a summary print out of the variables. Ideally the ability to supply more than two datasets would be great and if there was extra variables that weren't in one of the datasets, these would be at the end of the output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b"),
                  var2 = c("A", "B"),
                  var3 = c("checking"))
df1
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = letters,
                  var2 = LETTERS,
                  var4 = c("testing"))
df2
ll <- lst(df1, df2)

compare_these_lists <- map(ll, ~dplyr::select_if(.x, is.factor) %>% map(., tabyl))
compare_these_lists
```

the outcome I want is the following where each variable is aligned so they can easily be compared as so:

```
$df1                   $df2
$df1$var1              $df2$var1
.x[[i]] n percent     .x[[i]] n    percent
a 1     0.5                 a 1 0.03846154
b 1     0.5                 b 1 0.03846154
                            c 1 0.03846154
                            d 1 0.03846154
                            e 1 0.03846154
                            f 1 0.03846154
                            g 1 0.03846154
                            h 1 0.03846154
                            i 1 0.03846154
                            j 1 0.03846154
                            k 1 0.03846154
                            l 1 0.03846154
                            m 1 0.03846154
                            n 1 0.03846154
                            o 1 0.03846154
                            p 1 0.03846154
                            q 1 0.03846154
                            r 1 0.03846154
                            s 1 0.03846154
                            t 1 0.03846154
                            u 1 0.03846154
                            v 1 0.03846154
                            w 1 0.03846154
                            x 1 0.03846154
                            y 1 0.03846154
                            z 1 0.03846154

$df1$var2               $df2$var2
.x[[i]] n percent     .x[[i]] n    percent
A 1     0.5                 A 1 0.03846154
B 1     0.5                 B 1 0.03846154
                            C 1 0.03846154
                            D 1 0.03846154
                            E 1 0.03846154
                            F 1 0.03846154
                            G 1 0.03846154
                            H 1 0.03846154
                            I 1 0.03846154
                            J 1 0.03846154
                            K 1 0.03846154
                            L 1 0.03846154
                            M 1 0.03846154
                            N 1 0.03846154
                            O 1 0.03846154
                            P 1 0.03846154
                            Q 1 0.03846154
                            R 1 0.03846154
                            S 1 0.03846154
                            T 1 0.03846154
                            U 1 0.03846154
                            V 1 0.03846154
                            W 1 0.03846154
                            X 1 0.03846154
                            Y 1 0.03846154
                            Z 1 0.03846154     

$df1$var3
.x[[i]] n percent
checking 2       1                

                        $df2$var4
                         .x[[i]] n percent
                      testing 26       1
```

The only similar question I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213949/how-to-display-lists-side-by-side-in-r-a-cbind-for-lists) which is quite old but the variables jump around in that solution so they dont align up which makes it difficult to compare if you have lots of variables.

Is there already a function for doing something like this or any nice work around? I was thinking something with `purrr` might do it.

thanks

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this using a `left_join` by the correct variable and using a `select` to organize the columns as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this gets me close enough

```
library(tidyverse)
flatten(compare_these_lists) %>% 
  map( ~ .x %>%  mutate(id = row_number())) %>%   
  imap(~set_names(.x, ifelse(names(.x) != "id", paste(.y, names(.x), sep = "_"), names(.x)))) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = 'id') %>% 
  {map(set_names(c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")), function(.x) dplyr::select(., contains(.x)))}

# $var1
#    var1_.x[[i]].x var1_n.x var1_percent.x var1_.x[[i]].y var1_n.y var1_percent.y
# 1               a        1            0.5              a        1     0.03846154
# 2               b        1            0.5              b        1     0.03846154
# 3            <NA>       NA             NA              c        1     0.03846154
# 4            <NA>       NA             NA              d        1     0.03846154
# 5            <NA>       NA             NA              e        1     0.03846154
# 6            <NA>       NA             NA              f        1     0.03846154
# 7            <NA>       NA             NA              g        1     0.03846154
# 8            <NA>       NA             NA              h        1     0.03846154
# 9            <NA>       NA             NA              i        1     0.03846154
# 10           <NA>       NA             NA              j        1     0.03846154
# 11           <NA>       NA             NA              k        1     0.03846154
# 12           <NA>       NA             NA              l        1     0.03846154
# 13           <NA>       NA             NA              m        1     0.03846154
# 14           <NA>       NA             NA              n        1     0.03846154
# 15           <NA>       NA             NA              o        1     0.03846154
# 16           <NA>       NA             NA              p        1     0.03846154
# 17           <NA>       NA             NA              q        1     0.03846154
# 18           <NA>       NA             NA              r        1     0.03846154
# 19           <NA>       NA             NA              s        1     0.03846154
# 20           <NA>       NA             NA              t        1     0.03846154
# 21           <NA>       NA             NA              u        1     0.03846154
# 22           <NA>       NA             NA              v        1     0.03846154
# 23           <NA>       NA             NA              w        1     0.03846154
# 24           <NA>       NA             NA              x        1     0.03846154
# 25           <NA>       NA             NA              y        1     0.03846154
# 26           <NA>       NA             NA              z        1     0.03846154

# $var2
#    var2_.x[[i]].x var2_n.x var2_percent.x var2_.x[[i]].y var2_n.y var2_percent.y
# 1               A        1            0.5              A        1     0.03846154
# 2               B        1            0.5              B        1     0.03846154
# 3            <NA>       NA             NA              C        1     0.03846154
# 4            <NA>       NA             NA              D        1     0.03846154
# 5            <NA>       NA             NA              E        1     0.03846154
# 6            <NA>       NA             NA              F        1     0.03846154
# 7            <NA>       NA             NA              G        1     0.03846154
# 8            <NA>       NA             NA              H        1     0.03846154
# 9            <NA>       NA             NA              I        1     0.03846154
# 10           <NA>       NA             NA              J        1     0.03846154
# 11           <NA>       NA             NA              K        1     0.03846154
# 12           <NA>       NA             NA              L        1     0.03846154
# 13           <NA>       NA             NA              M        1     0.03846154
# 14           <NA>       NA             NA              N        1     0.03846154
# 15           <NA>       NA             NA              O        1     0.03846154
# 16           <NA>       NA             NA              P        1     0.03846154
# 17           <NA>       NA             NA              Q        1     0.03846154
# 18           <NA>       NA             NA              R        1     0.03846154
# 19           <NA>       NA             NA              S        1     0.03846154
# 20           <NA>       NA             NA              T        1     0.03846154
# 21           <NA>       NA             NA              U        1     0.03846154
# 22           <NA>       NA             NA              V        1     0.03846154
# 23           <NA>       NA             NA              W        1     0.03846154
# 24           <NA>       NA             NA              X        1     0.03846154
# 25           <NA>       NA             NA              Y        1     0.03846154
# 26           <NA>       NA             NA              Z        1     0.03846154

# $var3
#    var3_.x[[i]] var3_n var3_percent
# 1      checking      2            1
# 2          <NA>     NA           NA
# 3          <NA>     NA           NA
# 4          <NA>     NA           NA
# 5          <NA>     NA           NA
# 6          <NA>     NA           NA
# 7          <NA>     NA           NA
# 8          <NA>     NA           NA
# 9          <NA>     NA           NA
# 10         <NA>     NA           NA
# 11         <NA>     NA           NA
# 12         <NA>     NA           NA
# 13         <NA>     NA           NA
# 14         <NA>     NA           NA
# 15         <NA>     NA           NA
# 16         <NA>     NA           NA
# 17         <NA>     NA           NA
# 18         <NA>     NA           NA
# 19         <NA>     NA           NA
# 20         <NA>     NA           NA
# 21         <NA>     NA           NA
# 22         <NA>     NA           NA
# 23         <NA>     NA           NA
# 24         <NA>     NA           NA
# 25         <NA>     NA           NA
# 26         <NA>     NA           NA

# $var4
#    var4_.x[[i]] var4_n var4_percent
# 1       testing     26            1
# 2          <NA>     NA           NA
# 3          <NA>     NA           NA
# 4          <NA>     NA           NA
# 5          <NA>     NA           NA
# 6          <NA>     NA           NA
# 7          <NA>     NA           NA
# 8          <NA>     NA           NA
# 9          <NA>     NA           NA
# 10         <NA>     NA           NA
# 11         <NA>     NA           NA
# 12         <NA>     NA           NA
# 13         <NA>     NA           NA
# 14         <NA>     NA           NA
# 15         <NA>     NA           NA
# 16         <NA>     NA           NA
# 17         <NA>     NA           NA
# 18         <NA>     NA           NA
# 19         <NA>     NA           NA
# 20         <NA>     NA           NA
# 21         <NA>     NA           NA
# 22         <NA>     NA           NA
# 23         <NA>     NA           NA
# 24         <NA>     NA           NA
# 25         <NA>     NA           NA
# 26         <NA>     NA           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

Your reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b"),
                  var2 = c("A", "B"),
                  var3 = c("checking"))
df1
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = letters,
                  var2 = LETTERS,
                  var4 = c("testing"))
```

Creating a key to join dataframes:

```
df1 <- as_tibble(df1)
df1 <- df1 %>% rownames_to_column(var = "key")

df2 <- as_tibble(df2)
df2 <- df2 %>% rownames_to_column(var = "key")
```

full_join to compare:

```
df_compare <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "key")
print(df_compare)
```

Comment: thanks but thats not the output I was looking for, if you have hundreds of variables you will have a really wide dataset, its much easier to scroll vertically down as you would read a list as opposed to moving horizontally

Comment: Do you need to print these to the console, or can you write out to an Excel/text/other file?

Comment: both i suppose but if you can print to console, printing to something else should be straightforward I would think

Comment: only getting back to this! figured it out, thanks for pointing me towards `full_join`, see below